# What is a question mark for in the next expression in an angular 2 app

Tags: angular, binding, interpolation

Just wondering what does the question mark means in the next expression in an angular 2 app.

```html
<h1>
 Time Remaining: {{ currentExercise.duration? - exerciseRunningDuration }}
</h1>
```

Comment: it should be `?.` I wonder if its only `?`. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator

Comment: @micronyks The books has this example with just the question mark

Comment: @silentsod The example here does not use safe operator. The save operator is question mark and then a dot. Here is just a question mark at the end of an expression.

Comment: Strange... Where did you find this code?

Comment: @AngularFrance I am reading a book and it is inside as an example the book is "Angular 2 By Example", maybe it is a printing error

Comment: I think that it is. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is clearly typo/printing error. If you don't have `(.)` after `?` mark then, Angular template compiler will treat it as a **ternary operator**.

Answer (score 1):

Just complementing the @silentsod comment, because the documentation URL changed.

It's a typo for [safe navigation operator (?.)](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths)

```html
<h1>
 Time Remaining: {{ currentExercise?.duration - exerciseRunningDuration }}
</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answers have stated it is a typo and as Harshl have said if the  (.) was after ? mark, Angular treats it as a ternary operator. but if the statement was as:

```
<h1>
 Time Remaining: {{ currentExercise?.duration - exerciseRunningDuration }}
</h1>enter code here
```

the question mark acts as a **safe navigation operator**. "It provides a way to guard against null and undefined values in property paths.The expression bails out when it hits the first null value. The **display will be blank**, but the app will keep **rolling without errors**". ([Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths))

Furthermore, if the code was as follows:

```
<h1>
Time Remaining: {{ currentExercise.duration - exerciseRunningDuration }}
</h1>enter code here
```

If the 'duration' property of 'currentExercise' was null, Angular would throw a null reference error and the whole view would disappear. That is why using the **safe navigation operator** is important.

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1>
 Time Remaining: {{ currentExercise?.duration - exerciseRunningDuration }}
</h1>
```

The ? makes the property optional. If the parent scope property : currentExercise doesn't exist, it will throw a NON_ASSIGNABLE_MODEL_EXPRESSION exception. You can avoid this behavior using =? or =?attr in order to flag the property as optional.